# NSLocalizedString shows raw key instead of loading a string from another language

Tags: ios, swift, localization, localizable.strings

I'm having trouble using `NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")` to load strings from Localizable.strings when the key is missing for the current language. NSLocalizedString returns a raw key

For instance, when string is present for English localization, but is missing for Russian:

```
"config.updating" = "Update in progress...";
```

Calling NSLocalizedString when iOS language set to Russian returns "config.updating"

```
NSLocalizedString("config.updating", comment: "") // "config.updating"
```

Shouldn't NSLocalizedString access the "AppleLanguages" key in NSUserDefaults to determine what the user's settings are and pick some other string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedString) for `NSLocalizedString(key,comment)` is pretty clear -

> The initial value for `key` in the strings file will be `key`. Use the
>   `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue` macro to specify another value for
>   key.

What else would you expect it to return? The code simply looks up the key in a dictionary.  It has no idea what message is associated with the key, let alone how to translate that message into Russian.

Comment: So what is the use of base localization file?

Comment: The base localisation file is used when there is no specific localised version of the file available. E.g. if your app has a base localisation of English and you add French localisation, languages other than French will get the English values

Comment: Okay, then how to handle the situation, where I have Localizable files for Base(English), English, Japanese, but in Japanese file I haven't added any key-value strings. When I set the device language to Japanese it shows "key" only but it should show strings from Base(English) file?

Comment: No, because you have a Japanese localisation. The base file is only used where there isn't a localisation for that language, not when there is a missing key in the localised file. Where there is a localisation but the key is missing, the key value is shown

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create a `Build Phase run script` where you compare the keys of your translation between your base (say its `English`) with `Russian` and then if there is any difference you can either stop the build (`exit 1` after `echo "error:..."`) and show a build error with the missing keys as output or you can just show them as error and not stop the build.

**1) In your Build Phase Run Script:**

```
MISSING_KEYS_TRANSLATIONS=$(diff <($SRCROOT/tools/localization/check_missing_keys_in_translations.sh en) <($SRCROOT/tools/localization/check_missing_keys_in_translations.sh ru))
if [ "$MISSING_KEYS_TRANSLATIONS" ]; then
echo "error: $MISSING_KEYS_TRANSLATIONS"
fi
```

**2)** I have created in my `project root folder` a folder path like this `tools/localization/` where I have put a bash script **check_missing_keys_in_translations.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
plutil -convert json 'ProjectRootFolder/Resources/Localization/'"$1"'.lproj/Localizable.strings' -o - | ruby -r json -e 'puts JSON.parse(STDIN.read).keys.sort'
```

**3) Don't forget to make your script executable:**

`chmod a+x check_missing_keys_in_translations.sh`