# How can I automatically check for missing localizations in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

#### SourceFile.m

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Word 1", @"");
NSLocalizedString(@"Word 2", @"");
```

#### de.lproj/Localizable.strings

```
"Word 1" = "Wort 1";
"Word 2" = "Wort 2";
```

#### fr.lproj/Localizable.strings

```
/* Missing Word 1 */
"Word 2" = "Mot 2";
```

Is there a script or a compiler setting that will check that all localised strings are translated in all supported locales?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `diff` on the list of keys to see what's missing

Here's a shell script (let's call it `keys.sh`) to print out the keys of a given `.strings` file, sorted to `stdout`:

```
#!/bin/sh
plutil -convert json "$1".lproj/Localizable.strings -o - | ruby -r json -e 'puts JSON.parse(STDIN.read).keys.sort'
```

You can then use it combined with the `<(cmd)` shell syntax to compare keys between two localisations; for example to compare your `Base.lproj` and `fr.lproj`:

```
diff <(keys.sh Base) <(keys.sh fr)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Non-Localized Strings

Go under "Edit Scheme > Options" and check the "Show non-localized strings" box.

[image]

When you Build and Run you'll able to see warnings on Xcode command screen.

if you localized string like below:

```
lblTitle.text = NSLocalizedString("Lorem Ipsum", "")
```

then Xcode will printout a warning message on terminal like below:

```
ERROR Lorem Ipsum not found in table Localizable of bundle CFBundle ...
```

For storyboards, Xcode will throw a similar error.

Comment: It won't really "throw an error", you'll get a printout in the debug terminal if (and only if) you encounter a missing string in runtime. So to make use of this you have to manually run through every inch of the app, and then also check the terminal. Not a very good workflow IMO, and it's hardly "automatic".

Answer (score 1):

Not the perfect solution for your problem. But you could uses following plugin to check localization strings while coding.
https://github.com/questbeat/Lin

Also, I use to export localization string table from an Excel file or Google Sheet as a practice. This will make things easier and reduce lot of mistakes.

Comment: Lin looks like a nice tool, but its not what I am after since we localise after creating `NSLocalizedString`s.  We actually use phraseapp.com, which does highlight missing translations but I was after a script to run before we release to make sure there has been no mistakes in the import process.

Answer (score 0):

[**Check my example on how you can achieve it**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908367/3564632)

**To sum up**: you can create a `Run Script` under `Build Phase` in which you execute a `bash script` like suggested from @AliSoftware to compare your `Localizable.strings` and in case some keys are missing from one compared to the other you could either stop the build and output those missing keys as error or you could just output them as error and not let the build continue.