# Xcode UITest for different localizations strings

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xctestcase

So I am doing UITesting for different localizations.

This is my `Localizable.strings (English)` file

```
/* Hello */
"Hello" = "Hello";

/* Bye */
"Bye" = "Bye";
```

This is my `Localizable.strings (French)` file

```
/* Hello */
"Hello" = "bonjour";
```

Notice that the french strings file doesn't have the text for "Bye".

When I run my UITest, shown in [this GIF](https://gfycat.com/smoggylegalatlasmoth), how do I make the test fail if the text for a locale is missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32781556.

Comment: @MartinR thanks will check it out

Comment: @MartinR hi, i have found the answer after some digging. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to fail the test if a text is not localized for a language.

I added this in my UITest:

```
XCTAssertEqual(lblSecond.label, returnLocalizedText(textKey: "Bye"))
```

What this does is you pass in the key for your localized text, and check it whether it does match with the label's text. You can get the label's text like so:

```
//you can set this identifier in storyboard or in your VC like   
lblTitle.accessibilityIdentifier = "lblSecondIdentifier"

//Then in XCTest
let lblSecond = app.staticTexts["lblSecondIdentifier"]  
XCTAssert(lblSecond.isHittable) //check whether it exist first
```

Then this is the function. It will check whether the path exist and look for text, and finally return the localized string if it exists:

```
func returnLocalizedText(textKey: String) -> String{
    guard let languageCode = Locale(identifier: Locale.preferredLanguages.first!).languageCode else {
        XCTFail("languageCode not found")
        fatalError()
    }

    guard let path = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "Localizable", ofType: "strings", inDirectory: nil, forLocalization: languageCode) else{
        XCTFail("path not found")
        fatalError()
    }

    guard let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) else {
        XCTFail("dict not found")
        fatalError()
    }

    guard let text = dict.value(forKey: textKey) as? String else {
        XCTFail("text not found")
        fatalError()
    }
    return text
}
```

Comment: UI tests shall not include translation checks at all. You can do such checks a lot faster with `bash` scripts mentioned by Martin.